# How to consume messages using beam's external kafka transform (locally)

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, apache-beam, cross-language

I am trying to run an app that uses a **kafka producer (Python client)**, and an **apache beam pipeline** that will (for now) simply consume those messages by printing them to **STDOUT**.

I understand that using **Kafka external transform** with **apache beam** is a cross-language endeavor as it calls to a Java external service. I followed the [following link's](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.kafka.html) **Option 1** :

> Option 1: Use the default expansion service
>
> This is the recommended and easiest setup option for using Python
> Kafka transforms. This option is only available for Beam 2.22.0 and
> later.
>
> This option requires following pre-requisites before running the Beam
> pipeline.
>
> Install Java runtime in the computer from where the pipeline is
> constructed and make sure that ‘java’ command is available.

I am running `apache-beam==2.31.0`, and just installed java :

```
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing
```

I am not completely sure which runner I should use as the [portability documentation](https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability/) seems to point towards a `Universal Local Runner`, but I can't seem to find this runner
in the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/).

Here's the code sample I'm trying to make work:

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from helpers import ccloud_lib

from apache_beam.io.external.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


def run(argv=None):
    """Main entry point; runs a word_count pipeline"""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_topic",
        dest="input_topic",
        default="wordcount",
        help="Kafka topic to use for input",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--kafka_config",
        dest="config_file",
        default="config/confluent/python.config",
    )

    args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)[0]
    beam_options = PipelineOptions(runner="DirectRunner")

    consumer_conf = ccloud_lib.read_ccloud_config(args.config_file)
    consumer_conf["group.id"] = "python_wordcount_group_1"
    consumer_conf["auto.offset.reset"] = "earliest"

    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
        pipeline
        | "Read"
        >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config=consumer_conf,
            topics=[args.input_topic],
        )
        | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
```

I launch the module, but I don't undestand exactly how this works as some java artifacts seem to be downloaded and a docker image launched. I then get the following warning message :

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.worker_handlers:b'2021/08/25 14:38:05 Failed to obtain provisioning information: failed to dial server at localhost:36071\n\tcaused by:\ncontext deadline exceeded\n'
```

To summarize my questions, can you explain what goes on when I launch the script? And which runner should I be using to do this? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the universal runner is located under apache_beam.runners.portability.portable_runner.